# Обработка исключения в JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Я получаю с сервера ответы, например [image: Правильный ответ]

Но, иногда сервер возвращает подобное [image: Неполный ответ]

И когда я запрашиваю например `data.rows[1 (и больше)][1]`
Консоль выдает вот это

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined"

Что логично, я хочу сделать исключение, чтоб подобная ошибка обрабатывалась и `data.rows[1 (и больше)][1]` присваивались нули

Comment: проверяй `length` свойство перед обращением, чтобы не выйти за пределы

Comment: Как быть, если `data.rows = null` ?

Comment: Проверять наличие `data.rows`.

Comment: @Трик, как ни странно, но надо проверить и этот случай.

Answer (score 0):

Проверка существования свойств делается так:

```
if('data' in json) 1
```

Массивы обрабатывать надо созданными для этого средствами, например:

```
json.data.forEach(e => 1);
```

За рамки не выйдет.

---

Можно, конечно, извратиться, подключив генераторы/итераторы (хотя в массивах и так есть), но это дерьмодемон в мире кода, делать так не стоит.